# Can't access public method in an object passed to an Angular component's @Input field

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decorator

I've declared the following configurator object.

```
export class Config {
  constructor(public index: number, public junk: string[] = []) { }
  public count() : number { return this.junk.length; }
}
```

Then I pass it into my components input decorated field like this (`@Input() config : Config;`).

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of stuff; let config={index:index,junk:junk};">
  <app-thingy [data]="thing"
              [config]="config">
  </app-thingy>
</div>
```

When I access `this.config` (checking that it's been set in `ngOnChanges()`) I see the values I'm setting **but** I can't access the method. I also noticed that any additional parameters I might have in the constructor or possible public fields in the class aren't seen neither. Basically, only the fields assigned explicitly in the HTML markup are available.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (changes.config) {
    //console.log((new Config()).count());
    console.log((this.config.count()));
  }
}
```

The commented out line will produce an error saying that there's no such a method on the object. The second line proves it wrong - there is such a method on the object. I also tried casting it using `this.config as Config` but that led to the same result.

I'm sensing that the object I'm passing from the HTML markup isn't at all typed `Config` and hence, it doesn't have any methods/variables I haven't assigned explicitly. Since I can't just go `new Config(...)` in the markup (as asked for and responded to), I'm not sure how I'm supped to make the stupid computer trust me that it's dealing with a nicely implemented class **including** its convenience method.

How should I deal with it?

The best approach to it I can imagine is to construct an internal `Config` object making a copy of the fields from the passed in  object and then to bind the HTML interpolators to that instead. However, it seems soooo hacky that I'm certain it's either stupid or wrong (possibly both)...

Comment: What's up with `let config={index:index,junk=junk};"` in template? not related to current error, but I'd assume it would throw error as well?

Comment: Typo. It's supposed to be colon not equality sign. I shortened it down a bit and made a mistake. Correcting the question right now. Good eyes, mate!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with `let config={index:index,junk:junk};` in your code, and that would throw an error, at least when I just now tried it. When removing this line and  properly declaring a new `Config` in your parent, your code should work.

Parent:

```
config = new Config(1,['one','two'])
```

Parent html:

```
<div *ngFor="let thing of stuff">
  <app-thingy [data]="thing" [config]="config"></app-thingy>
</div>
```

Child:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
  if (changes.config) {
    //console.log((new Config()).count());
    console.log((this.config.count()));
  }
}
```

This seems to work just fine! DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnmk41?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You're sending in the same config object for each iteration. I need to be able to send in difference instances (e.g. index) which aren't available to me until the actual iteration, are they?

Comment: It's real hard to help to not knowing the usecase here with only pseudocode. What is this `config`? What is dynamic about it?

Comment: My bad, I'm sorry. The use case is that I need to pass in *index* to keep the background coloring in sync (and also *first* and *last* to set some styling on the sub-components).

Comment: I'm still not able to understand how you even get data to your input with the code `<div *ngFor="let thing of stuff; let config={index:index,junk:junk};">` that just throws error :D

Comment: I don't. I had to retype the code to keep the question shortest possible and made a booboo. The actual code is `let first=first;let last=last;` etc. Totally my bad. The point of the question is, though, that I find it a bit overly verbose and was suspecting that there's  a neater way to achieve the result. So - is there a way to make it shorter? (Sorry about the initial confusion, mate.)

Comment: "made a booboo" :D Sure, I'll look at your code a bit later, still at work, so I guess I should pretend I'm working :D